# An application of Jensen's Inequality for dependent random variables

Tags: probability, expectation

Consider dependent and positive valued random variables $A,B$ and $X$. I want to prove that 
\begin{equation}
E[X^2 A] E[B] \ge E[X A] E[X B].
\end{equation}

If $A$ and $B$ were scalars, above would hold due to Jensen's Inequality. I wonder whether there would be a proof using a similar logic.

Comment: Since you know the result for scalars, perhaps it would help to write something like $E[X^2 A]=\int E[X^2 A|A=a]dP(A=a)=\int aE[X^2 | A=a]dP(A=a)$?

Comment: Without some supplementary hypotheses, there is no reason to believe this inequality should hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying a very dependent set of random variables, let
$$
(A,B,X)=(1,0,1)\text{ with probability }\tfrac12
$$
and
$$
(A,B,X)=(0,1,4)\text{ with probability }\tfrac12
$$
Then
$$
E\left[AX^2\right]=\tfrac12\quad\text{and}\quad E[B]=\tfrac12
$$
and
$$
E[AX]=\tfrac12\quad\text{and}\quad E[BX]=2
$$
Therefore,
$$
E\left[AX^2\right]E[B]=\tfrac14\lt1=E[AX]\,E[BX]
$$